# How to get timestamp(rowversion) from sql azure to android with mobileservice

Tags: android, sql, azure, timestamp, azure-mobile-services

i have a problem getting timestamp(rowversion) from my SQL Azure database.
In my tables there is a column with datatype timestamp. This timestamp isn't similar to datetime, it's more like a rowversion.
I can get all other data in this table with the query from MobileServiceTable, there is no problem.
But this special datatype is a problem.
My class for this table looks like:

```
public class ArbeitsgangBezeichnung {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private int ID;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("ABZ_ArbeitsgangBezeichnungID")
    private int ABZ_ArbeitsgangBezeichnungID;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("ABZ_Bezeichnung")
    private String ABZ_Bezeichnung;
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("ABZ_RowVersion")
    private StringMap<Number> ABZ_RowVersion;
    //constructor, getter, setter, etc....
}
```

If i login in Azure and look at the table, there are my example values and the automatic generated timestamp. The timestamp value looks like "AAAAAAAAB/M=". If i login in sql database and let me show the data, then for timestamp there is only "binarydata" (in pointed brackets) and not that value as it is shown in Azure.

The variable "ABZ_RowVersion" should include this timestamp, but the data in the StringMap doesn't look like the one in Azure. I tried String and Byte as datatype for the StringMap, but it doesn't helped.

I tried byte[] for ABZ_RowVersion, but then i got an exception in the callback method.
Then i tried Object for ABZ_RowVersion, that time i found out, that it is a StringMap, but nothing more.

Does anybody know, how to get the data from timestamp, i need it for comparison.

Thanks already

Comment: According to MSDN a rowversion (timestamp) is equivalent to binary(8), which is equivalent to a byte array with a length of 8. The output you see on the screen when running a select statement is probably encoded to be displayed. But the raw data is a byte array. Hope this helps.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Comment: when i changed my datatype from ABZ_RowVersion to byte array, then i get an exception in the callback method which says "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT". maybe trying with StringMap<byte>, iterate through the map and put it all in an extra byte array.

Comment: When i try it with StringMap<Number> then i get an entrySet with "[0=0, 1=0, 2=0, 3=0, 4=0, 5=0, 6=7, 7=243, length=8]". Where is the connection to the value i see in Azure, or is the value in Azure misleading, as you say it is probably encoded?

Comment: Today i could solve this problem. Each entry in the StringMap represents an 8-bit array. How you say, it is a byte array with a length of 8. Counting all numbers together: 0*2^56 + 0*2^48 + 0*2^40 + 0*2^32 + 0*2^24 + 0*2^16 + 7*2^8 + 243*2^0, then i get 2035. If i login in sql database and make "SELECT CAST(ABZ_RowVersion in int)" then i get this 2035. And i could make "select * from [table] where ABZ_RowVersion = 2035" and get the right row.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a `timestamp` column in a table, it's essentially a `varbinary(8)` column. In the node SQL driver, it's mapped to a `Buffer` type (the usual node.js type used for binary data). The object which you see (`{"0":0, "1":0, ..., "length":8}`) is the way that a buffer is *stringified* into JSON. That representation doesn't map to the default byte array representation from the Gson serializer in Android (or to the `byte[]` in the managed code).

To be able to use timestamp columns, the first thing you need to do is to "teach" the serializer how to understand the format of the column returned by the server. You can do that with a `JsonDeserializer<byte[]>` class:

```
public class ByteArrayFromNodeBufferGsonSerializer
    implements JsonDeserializer<byte[]> {

    @Override
    public byte[] deserialize(JsonElement element, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (element == null || element.isJsonNull()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            JsonObject jo = element.getAsJsonObject();
            int len = jo.get("length").getAsInt();
            byte[] result = new byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                String key = Integer.toString(i);
                result[i] = jo.get(key).getAsByte();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to *read* data. There's still another problem, though. On insert and update operations, the value of the column is sent by the client, and SQL doesn't let you set them in them. So let's take this class:

```
public class Test {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int mId;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String mName;

    @SerializedName("version")
    private byte[] mVersion;

    public int getId() { return mId; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.mId = id; }

    public String getName() { return mName; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.mName = name; }

    public byte[] getVersion() { return mVersion; }
    public void setVersion(byte[] version) { this.mVersion = version; }
}
```

On the insert and update operations, the first thing we need to do in the server-side script is to remove that property from the object. And there's another issue: after the insert is done, the runtime doesn't return the rowversion property (i.e., it doesn't update the `item` variable. So we need to perform a lookup against the DB to retrieve that column as well:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
    delete item.version;
    request.execute({
        success: function() {
            tables.current.lookup(item.id, {
                success: function(inserted) {
                    request.respond(201, inserted);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And the same on update:

```
function update(item, user, request) {
    delete item.version;
    request.execute({
        success: function() {
            tables.current.lookup(item.id, {
                success: function(updated) {
                    request.respond(200, updated);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Now, this definitely is a lot of work - the support for this type of column should be better. I've created a feature request in the UserVoice page at http://mobileservices.uservoice.com/forums/182281-feature-requests/suggestions/4670504-better-support-for-timestamp-columns, so feel free to vote it up to help the team prioritize it.